# How to create a virtualenv with Python3 while my system is OsX 10 with Python2

Tags: python, macos, virtualenvwrapper

My machine is OsX 10.10.2 and I have Python 2 installed.

It is possible to create a virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper command mkvirtualenv to run on Python 3?
I am reluctant to install Python3 in my system as the last time I did that, python on the whole stopped working. Not sure why, I am a new. May I screwed up. I am looking for the command to run.

Comment: You can use the `-p` arg like so -- `virtualenv -p $(which python3)`

Comment: @BrianCain Thank you for the answer. Not sure how to mark it as you posted in the comment.

For other newbies, since I am using mkvirtualenv, the command is:
mkvirtualenv -p $(which python3) nameOfEnvironment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-p` arg like so -- `virtualenv -p $(which python3)`

Comment: For other newbies, since I am using mkvirtualenv, the command is: mkvirtualenv -p $(which python3) nameOfEnvironment